# How To Configure cypress-grep plugin v3.1.0 for Cypress v11.01?

Tags: typescript, cypress, yarnpkg, cypress-grep

#### Cypress Version

11.0.1

#### Node Version

16.16.0

#### Package Manager

Yarn version 1.22.19

#### Operating System

Windows 10 Pro Version 21H2

I've created a [cypress_grep_test_project](https://github.com/Zujaj/cypress_grep_test_project) to practice this plugin and used the default sample spec files that Cypress provides during the first-time configuration. I just changed some spec files from "cy.js" to "cy.ts." I aim to use this plugin and test it out for Continuous Integration.

According to the [Cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/plugins-guide#Using-a-plugin), the plugins folder no longer exists. Following the [current documentation of the plugin](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/tree/develop/npm/grep#support-file), the `registerCypressGrep` method isn't available anymore.

I've added the `@cypress/grep` to the `ts.config` file.

```
//ts.config file
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": [
      "cypress",
      "@cypress/grep" // Added this to prevent tags issue
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

In the `todo.cy.ts` file, I inserted the `{ tags: 'smoke' }` to the `describe` block as shown in below snippet.

```
// todo.cy.ts
describe('example to-do app', { tags: 'smoke' }, () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io/todo')
  })
```

Now I don't know what to do next, can someone please help me with this?

```
// cypress.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    video: false,
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    // What next?
    },
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [mahadazad](https://github.com/mahadazad) for your collaboration.

Although this is just a workaround, I hope we'll get a proper solution to this problem very soon.

1. Navigate to the **`cypress\support\e2e.ts`** file.

[image: Navigation To e2e.ts file]

2. Add the below code with `@ts-ignore` to ignore typescript compiler warnings.

```
// e2e.ts file

import './commands'

// @ts-ignore
import registerCypressGrep from '@cypress/grep' 

registerCypressGrep()
```

3. Run the command `npx cypress run --env grepTags=smoke` on the terminal.

[image: Result]